# Meaning of "living" in "people living in its shadow"

Tags: meaning-in-context, gerunds

Let us consider this news title :

> Taal volcano eruption poses deadly dilemma for people living in its shadow

What does the expression "people living" mean here?

1) The people who live in its shadow

2) The live of people, in general, in its shadow

And please tell me about the reason, because the use of gerunds disturbs me a lot.

Comment: The gerund-participial clause "living in its shadow" modifies "people". It has the same meaning as the relative clause "who live in its shadow".

Comment: So it is choice number 1... Is it (choice num 1) only used in the news? And how can I express choice number 2, is it : "people's life" ?